# find nearest key match with input value greater or equal to key and records unsorted

Tags: perl, awk

I'm having the below input file and trying to find out the nearest key match with input value greater or equal to key. It works when the input file is sorted.

Input file:

```
10,Line1
20,Line2
30,Line3
40,Line4
50,Line5
55,Line6
70,Line7
75,Line8
90,Line9
95,Line10
99,Line11
```

Code that I tried:

```
$ awk -F,  -v inp=85 ' NR==1 { dp=0 } {  dt=($1-inp); d=sqrt(dt*dt); if(d<=dp && inp >= $1 ) { rec=$0 } dp=d } END { print rec } ' source.txt
75,Line8

$ awk -F,  -v inp=55 ' NR==1 { dp=0 } {  dt=($1-inp); d=sqrt(dt*dt); if(d<=dp && inp >= $1 ) { rec=$0 } dp=d } END { print rec } ' source.txt
55,Line6
```

It works fine when the source.txt is sorted on the key column i.e first. But it gives incorrect results when the file is not sorted

```
$ shuf source.txt | awk -F,  -v inp=85 ' NR==1 { dp=0 } {  dt=($1-inp); d=sqrt(dt*dt); if(d<=dp && inp >= $1 ) { rec=$0 } dp=d } END { print rec } ' 
50,Line5   # Wrong
```

Can this be fixed for the unsorted file?.

Solutions using any unix tools are welcome!

Comment: How do this relate to `sqlite`?

Comment: if the file can be treated as a table using sqlite3 im fine.. if not i can untag it

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to process a file as a table with sqlite. For this, you would need to load the file in a database table, then use sql. It is probably more straightforward to do it with a unix tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl

```
perl -0777 -wnE' $in = shift // 85;
    %h = split /(?:\s*,\s*|\s*\n\s*)/; 
    END { --$in while not exists $h{$in}; say "$in, $h{$in}" }
' data.txt 57
```

Notes

- read the whole file into a string ("slurp"), by `-0777`
- populate a hash with file data; I strip surrounding spaces in the process
- count down from input-value and check for such a key, until we get to one that exists
- input is presumed integer and being in range

The nearest key is the first one that `exists` as input "clicks" down toward it an integer at a time.

The invocation above (for `57`) prints the line:   `55, Line6`.

---

A version that *does* check the range of input and allows non-integer input

```
perl -MList::Util=min -0777 -wnE' $in = int shift // 85;
    %h = split /(?:\s*,\s*|\s*\n\s*)/; 
    die "Input $in out of range\n" if $in < min keys %h;
    END { --$in while not exists $h{$in}; say "$in, $h{$in}" }
' data.txt 57
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v n=85 'n>=$1 && (max=="" || $1>max){max=$1; rec=$0} END{print rec}' file
```

```
75,Line8
```

Run this again with a different value:

```
awk -F, -v n=55 'n>=$1 && (max=="" || $1>max){max=$1; rec=$0} END{print rec}' file
```

```
55,Line6
```

Comment: This might fail if you have negative keys and `max=0`. It is better to test for `max==""`

Comment: The clear, simple, foolproof way is to initialize max to the first value in the input.

Comment: @anubhava for unsorted lines, it is not working correctly. just give ````<(tac file)```` and you will see the difference.

Comment: @stack0114106: I have just updated it. Please try it now.

Answer (score 2):

Following code comply with your requirement

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $target = shift
    or die "Please enter a value";

my $line;

while( <DATA> ) {
    my @data = split ',';

    last if $data[0] > $target;

    $line = $_;
}

print $line;

__DATA__
10,Line1
20,Line2
30,Line3
40,Line4
50,Line5
55,Line6
70,Line7
75,Line8
90,Line9
95,Line10
99,Line11
```

Comment: this may not work, if the __DATA__ is not sorted.. pls check

Answer (score 0):

Code for unsorted lines

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $target = shift
    or die "Please enter a value";

my @lines = <DATA>;
my $line;
my %data;

map { my @array = split ',', $_; $data{$array[0]} = $_ } @lines;

foreach my $key ( sort keys %data ) {
    last if $key > $target;

    $line = $data{$key};
}

print $line;

__DATA__
10,Line1
20,Line2
30,Line3
40,Line4
50,Line5
55,Line6
70,Line7
75,Line8
90,Line9
95,Line10
99,Line11
```